# Better Way To Get Char Enum

Tags: c#, enums, char

Is there a cleaner way to get the char value of an enum in C#.

```
 public enum DivisionStatus
        {
            None = 'N',
            Active = 'A',
            Inactive = 'I',
            Waitlist = 'W'
        }

string status = Enums.DivisionStatus.Active.ToString()[0].ToString(); // "A"
```

Comment: OmG... Good that you asked here.

Comment: You were asking of a _cleaner_ way to get the char value, but you do not get the char value _at all_. You get the first character of the name of the constant. If you changed the char value of Active to 'B', the result woudl still be "A".

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Just cast the value:

```
char status = (char)Enums.DivisionStatus.Active;
```

Note that this will use the value instead of the identifier. The `Enums.DivisionStatus.Active` value is the character code of `'A'`, as that is the value that you have defined.

Using the value directly is faster than looking up the identifier for the value.

Comment: The underlying type can be any integral type except char: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I think I didn't explain it correctly. If I wanted it has a string as the ending result and not a char.

Comment: @MikeFlynn: I see, I assumed that you wanted a char value when you asked for a char value. ;) Then just add `.ToString()` at the end, that is the simplest way to create a string from the enumeration value.

Comment: How to convert string to the enum type. I am storing the enum value in string in the DB. 
So, when storing I do ((char)Enums.DivisionStatus.Active).ToString() => 'A'.
How do I get the 'A' => Enums.DivisionStatusActive. @Guffa

Comment: I solved it my self `(Enums.DivisionStatus)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Enums.DivisionStatus), src.AddressDeliverabilityCode[0]`

Answer (score 7):

You could also use a static class.  Although, if you're always going to use the values as strings, you could just as easily make each property a string instead.  One advantage of this method is that you can add descriptions for each item that will show up in the IntelliSense.

```
public static class DivisionStatus
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Some information about None
    /// </summary>
    public const char None = 'N';
    /// <summary>
    /// Some information about Active, blah blah
    /// </summary>
    public const char Active = 'A';
    /// <summary>
    /// Some information about Inactive, blah blah
    /// </summary>
    public const char Inactive = 'I';
    /// <summary>
    /// Some information about Waitlist, blah blah
    /// </summary>
    public const char Waitlist = 'W';
}
```

Comment: This can't be uased as member of the class.

Answer (score 6):

I build a "pseudo-enum" that solves the problem. In your case it could look like:

```
public class DivisionStatus
{
    public static readonly DivisionStatus None = new DivisionStatus('N');
    public static readonly DivisionStatus Active = new DivisionStatus('A');
    public static readonly DivisionStatus Inactive = new DivisionStatus('I');
    public static readonly DivisionStatus Waitlist = new DivisionStatus('W');

    internal char Value { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }

    protected DivisionStatus(char value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

You can use it like an enum that returns the char enum value on ToString() without casting:

```
Console.WriteLine(DivisionStatus.None); // returns 'N'
```

Comment: This does not return 'N', DivisionStatus.None.ToString() returns 'N'

Comment: Any specific reason why this class shouldn't be sealed?

Answer (score 3):

Simple casting works, I tried it:

```
using System;

public enum DivisionStatus
{
  None = 'N',
  Active = 'X',
  Inactive = 'I',
  Waitlist = 'W'
}

class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var ds = DivisionStatus.Active;
    Console.WriteLine((char)ds);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just cast the enum value without calling ToString:

```
var status = (char)DivisionStatus.Active;
```

Or maybe you'd need to do

```
var status = (char)(int)DivisionStatus.Active;
```

Answer (score 1):

`var status = (char)Enums.DivisionStatus.Active;` should do exactly what you want. The way you were doing it before wouldn't have worked if the first character of the enum text didn't match the underlying char value.

This also works for enums that have an int as a backing type.

Comment: The enum does have an int as a backing type (as it's the default). The char values that are used in the definition are implicitly converted to int values.